# Java GUI Fill Combo box values with ArrayList

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, arraylist, combobox

I am trying to fill the ComboBox with the values of an ArrayList, but I do not know how. I want the data to come out the main from ArrayList COM = new ArrayList();. What I already have:

```
private void initComponents() {
    selectedComPort = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

    selectedComPort.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "COM 1", "COM 2" }));
    selectedComPort.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            selectedComPortActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
}

private void selectedComPortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Search all available COM ports and put them into a ArrayList
    ArrayList&lt;String&gt; COM = new ArrayList&lt;String&gt;();
    Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
            System.out.println("No COM ports found");
            } else {
            COM.add(portId.getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(COM);
}

private javax.swing.JComboBox selectedComPort;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
private void initComponents() {
 List<String> COM = new ArrayList<String>();
 Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
 while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
        System.out.println("No COM ports found");
        } else {
        COM.add(portId.getName());
    }
}

 selectedComPort = new JComboBox(COM.toArray(new String[COM.size()]));
 ....
}
```

Comment: Where then? If I put it outside the main, it does not find COM. This doesn't work..

Comment: I have two classes, ArduinoDisplay.java and DisplayForm.java. the gui is within DisplayForm.java, and I start it by using ` ArduinoDisplay main = new ArduinoDisplay();
        main.initialize();` in void main of ArduinoDisplay.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54728/discussion-between-masud-and-f4llcon).

Comment: Thank you very much, I had to right click the ComboBox and hit Customize Code, than add your code, and for the last line of code, I had to change Default code to Custom creation at the left side. Thanks, it works now :)

Comment: @F4LLCON, You're welcome. I guess you use Drag and Drop pallets of Netbeans. This is bad practice and difficult to maintain. So, try to avoid it.